# Is an object that contains a fixed set of mutable objects mutable?

Tags: java, mutability

Mutability still confuses me from time to time.

If I have an object that contains a fixed set of mutable objects. Do you consider this object mutable?

Example:
I have an object called Puzzle which containts a fixed set of Pieces. The Pieces are mutable. For example, they can be upsideDown and its orientation can change. Assuming you cannot loose pieces in this example (if only that were true in real life...), I guess the Puzzle object is still immutable, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From wikipedia:
In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object (unchangeable object) is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created. This is in contrast to a mutable object (changeable object), which can be modified after it is created.

In your example the Puzzle object is mutable because you can change the state of one of its Pieces.

Comment: Okay, so an immutable object cannot contain mutable objects? There is some kind of inheritance involved. Consequently, immutability is quite a bit harder to achieve then I thought it would be. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. If you want object to be immutable, then it can't contain mutable objects. Technically it is possible to make those mutable objects private and encapsulate them in such way that they can't be changed and you would achieve immutability, but that really depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

No. The object would be mutable. An important thing with immutability is that (pure) functions that take the object as a parameter returns the same value each time it is called. This would not be the case if the object contains mutable properties. Consider this example:

A mutable class:

```
class Counter {
    private int count = 0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count++;
    }
}
```

An "immutable" class:

```
class Container {
    private final Counter theCounter = new Counter();

    public Counter getCounter() { return theCounter; }
}
```

And a seemingly pure function that operates on a `Container`:

```
public int getCount(Container container) {
    return container.getCounter().getCount();
}
```

So, if `Container` was immutable, you would expect that `getCount()` would return the same value if the same `Container` was passed to it twice. But this is not the case.

```
Container container = new Container();
getCount(container); // Returns 0.
getCount(container); // Returns 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

No,an object can't be immutable if it contains atleast one mutable object.
Here the pieces are mutable. So Puzzle can't be immutable.

If you want to make Puzzle immutable, some how make the pieces immutable according to the requirement.

Comment: In my example, I guess it is no straightforward to make pieces immutable. The player must be able to rotate the pieces, for one.

Comment: Instead of mutating the actual piece, you can have a function `rotate` that returns a new piece which is rotated. There is always a way to make a class immutable.

Comment: I guess... but somehow my gut feeling says that is not the right way to go. Perhaps I am too attached to actual puzzles where you don't go around creating new pieces when you rotate a piece. So I guess my follow-up question for you: Yes, it is possible, but would you?